# Text decoration will not work

Tags: css, text, text-decorations

so my code is:

```
.bar {
 float: right;
 height: 283px;
 width: 567px;
 background: url('News.png');
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-right: 21%;

}

.bar > #text {

margin-top: 6%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-left: 6%;
width: 100%

.bar > #text > a {

text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;

}
```

I really do not know why 'text-decoration' will not work, Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't close your .bar > #text  line.

Answer (score 4):

This line was not closed:

```
.bar > #text {

margin-top: 6%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-left: 6%;
width: 100%
```

Needs to be:

```
.bar > #text {

margin-top: 6%;
margin-right: 10%;
margin-left: 6%;
width: 100%

}
```